# How to get instance of DiscountModel in Commerce 2?

Tags: plugin-development, plugin-craftcommerce, models

In Commerce i got an instance of DiscountModel Class as follows:

```
$discount = new Commerce_DiscountModel();
```

Is this the right way in Commerce 2?

```
use craft\commerce\models\Discount as DiscountModel;
...
$discount = DiscountModel::instance();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$discount = new \craft\commerce\models\Discount();
```

Comment: Thanks. Is that the same as: use craft\commerce\models\Discount as DiscountModel; $discount = new DiscountModel(); ?

Comment: @phaetons It's the same. In the latter, you're using a namespace alias: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php

Comment: Thanks Brad! I really need to update my PHP7 skills...